# Rails: Finding matching attribute in a has-many / belongs-to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a `Restaurant` and a `Reservation` model.  I want to find the reservations for each restaurant according to restaurant id, something like this:

```
@reservations = Reservation.find( # current user )
@restaurants = []
@reservations.each do |res|
  @restaurants += Restaurant.where('id like ?', res.rest_id)
end
```

When trying this, this constructs an array, which I've tried to convert to an Active Record object un-successfully. Am I missing something, or is there a more obvious way to do this ?

Comment: Try `Reservation.includes(:restaurant)`

Comment: `find` fetches a single entry. You meant `where`, right? Or something as neat as `current_user.reservations`.

Comment: Well, I'm stuck, your code and question don't quite match. Your code fetches all **restaurants** that have a reservation made by current user. Is that it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#load all reservations matching your condition, and eager-load all associated restaurants
@reservations = Reservation.where(<some condition>).includes(:restaurants)

#get all associated restaurants for all objects in the @reservations collection 
#which have been eager loaded, so this won't hit the db again), 
#flatten them to a single array, 
#then call `uniq` on this array to get rid of duplicates
@restaurants = @reservations.map(&:restaurants).flatten.uniq
```

EDIT - added `flatten`, added explanation in comments

Comment: This works, but do you also mind explaining how it works ? thanks a lot.

Comment: added some explanation.  I'm actually surprised it worked because i forgot to flatten the results of `@reservations.map(&:restaurants)` in my original answer: you would have had an array of arrays rather than an array of Restaurant objects.

Answer (score 1):

restaurant.rb

```
has_many :reservations
```

reservation

```
belongs_to :restaurant, class_name: 'Restaurant', foreign_key: 'rest_id'
```

You can find restaurant record for this reservation as

```
@reservation = Reservation.joins(:restaurant).where(id: reservation_id)
```